# try to push session when login laravel

Tags: laravel-5.1

I have problem when I try to push session when validate login into laravel.
My code following syntax:

```
$valid = DB::table('users')
                        ->select(DB::raw('count(email) as email'))
                        ->where('email' , '=', $request['email'])
                        ->where('password', '=', bcrypt($request['password']))
                        ->first();
        $count = $valid->email;
        if($count > 1) {
            $permit = DB::table('users')
                ->select('permit')->where('email' ,'=', $request['email'])->first();
            $permit = $permit->permit;
            $user_id = DB::table('users')
                ->select('user_id')->where('email' ,'=', $request['email'])->first();
            $user_id = $user_id->user_id;
            Session::flush();
            Session::push('permit', $permit);
            Session::push('user_id', $user_id);
        }
```

I know method bcrypt() not return the same string another time, so what can I do for problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt method to login

```
  if( Auth::attempt(['email' =>$request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']])){
 return view('dashnorad')//login success

 }else{

return view('login')//login fiald
}
```

and for access to user field like this

```
Auth::user()->username
```

import auth class in controller

```
use Auth;
```

Comment: I tried,
>
` if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
            Session::push();
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath())->
                withInput()->with('message', 'Login successful');
        }
else  if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            Session::push();
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath())->
                withInput()->with('message', 'Login successful');
        }
`
but not working,..

Comment: error not show. Email,password invalid, it's will show error invalid, and if correct, nothing happent, not redirect not show error,..

Comment: when you use attemp method you can not bcrypt password

Comment: Yep, I know.But when using attempt method follow your suggested, i don't use bcrypt() method before.

Comment: when email, password invalid, it's will show error invalid, and if correct, nothing happent, not redirect not show error.